# set js-cookie value to firebase token

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, js-cookie

Is it ok to set the value of a cookie to a token? I'm using js-cookie, Firebase auth/firestore and Next.js and I have my cookie set like this inside of my handleUser function:

```
  const handleUser = async (rawUser) => {
    if (rawUser) {
      const user = await formatUser(rawUser)
      const { token, ...userWithoutToken } = user

      createUser(user.uid, userWithoutToken)
      setUser(user)

      cookie.set('colorizer-auth', token, {
        expires: 1
      })

      setLoading(false)
      return user
    } else {
      setUser(false)
      cookie.remove('colorizer-auth')

      setLoading(false)
      return false
    }
   }
```

and the token is decoded and set here:

```
const formatUser = async (user) => {
  const decodedToken = await user.getIdTokenResult(true);
  const { token, expirationTime } = decodedToken;
  return {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    name: user.displayName,
    provider: user.providerData[0].providerId,
    photoUrl: user.photoURL,
    token,
    expirationTime,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some projects that use the Firebase Auth ID Token (`access_token`) itself in the cookies but that token is valid only for 1 hour. You'll have to securely store the `refresh_token` as well so you can refresh the cookie once it expires.

However, I would recommend using [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) instead for such SSR application. You can set the expiration time ranging 5 minutes to 2 weeks. It might be best to reauthenticate user after this expires.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I will check out the session cookie. Do you happen to know if your able to verify session cookies inside of NextJS getServerSideProps?

Comment: @RobbieC there is a `verifySessionCookie` method as in the documentation linked in my answer.